# Rails - using capitalize on a month name from l18n

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-4

I have a string like this in my view

```
<%= l event.start_date, format: :long %>
```

which outputs

18 aout 2013

I would like to capitalize the month name without touching the yaml file, and tried several options which failed miserably. Is it possible?

Answer (score 0):

If you call capitalize it only takes the first character, so you may use titleize

```
<%=(l Date.today, format: :long) %>
=> "Miércoles, 28 de agosto de 2013"
<%=(l Date.today, format: :long).titleize  %>
=> "Miércoles, 28 De Agosto De 2013"
```

Please note that all the words are turned to capital letter

Update

```
$ rails c
Loading development environment (Rails 4.0.0)
>> helper.l Date.today, format: :long
=> "September 02, 2013"
>> helper.l Time.now, format: :long
=> "September 02, 2013 22:56"
```

Comment: It's rare, because actually I'm using it in my apps, also the answer I copy from my rails console

Comment: can you model it with my example?

Comment: Excuse me for the delay, you can call you rails helpers in the console using helper.method,